# Отправка формы без использования PHP

Tags: html

Есть код страницы HTML:

> `<form id="form" action="act.html" method="post" target="_blank">
> <input type="text" name="txt" value="777">
> <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
> </form>`

Как видите, форма отправляет данные на файл 'act.html'. Вот содержимое файла 'act.html':

> `<span style="color: red;" name="txt"></span>`

Как отправить эту форму без использования PHP? Если это возможно, то насколько это сложнее? Если сделать это просто, то подскажите, как.

Comment: Я задал этот вопрос, потому что мой сайт, на котором я программирую, не поддерживает язык PHP. И тем более я ни капли в этом языке не разбираюсь.

Comment: Нужно, чтобы в элементе span появилось значение из поля text?

Comment: Тут вопрос не в отправке данных (по сабмиту данные итак отправятся), а в их обработке. Сделать это без какого-либо обработчика на бэкэнде невозможно. (Обработчик может быть написан не на php)

Comment: @RedMonkey можно принять get данные.

Comment: @Никита___ либо изменить логику передачи сообщений, либо искать место для вашего сайта с серверной частью.

Comment: @lampa можно, правда тут стоит post =)

Comment: @Никита___ давай уже определимся, что должно быть в результате, а то вдруг я тебя в другой лес повёл

Comment: Вод ход событий:
Клик на Submit...Открытие 'act.html' в новой вкладке...Отображение текста '777'. Что-то типа того)

Comment: У вас нет вариантов?

Comment: @Никита___ варианты вам предоставили, выбирайте уж сами.

Comment: Если делать через сервер, то тут к PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby, ASP.NET, Java, Groovy, node.js. Из них я только php знаю =). Если городить кривую логику, то можно и через js на клиенте сделать.

Comment: Ну уж если совсем не будет вариантов, то как-нибудь можно будет и через Javascript формы наколобродить) xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form id="form" action="act.html" method="get" target="_blank">
<input type="text" name="txt" value="777">
<input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

**act.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function loaddata(){
var tmp = new Array();    // два вспомогательных
  var tmp2 = new Array();  // массива
  get = new Array();

  var url = location.search;    // строка GET запроса
  if(url != '') {
    tmp = (url.substr(1)).split('&');   // разделяем переменные
    for(var i=0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
      tmp2 = tmp[i].split('=');     // массив get будет содержать
      get[tmp2[0]] = tmp2[1];       // пары ключ(имя переменной)->значение
    }
  }
//дальше заполняем все, что нам надо данными из массива get
document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = get['txt'];
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad='loaddata()'>
<span style="color: red;" name="txt" id="txt"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Наконец-то я сделал возможное из невозможного! xD

Comment: Ты сделал? Сомневаюсь.

Comment: Почему сомневаетесь? У меня всё получилось.

Answer (score 3):

Вариант 1: используем только GET запросы, параметры получаем через JavaScript ([How to retrieve GET parameters from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript))

Вариант 2: используем серверный язык программирования. Их на самом деле очень много, выбирайте на свой вкус (PHP, Node.JS, .NET, Java, Python, Perl, Scala ...)

Comment: А через запрос GET можно сделать те действия, которые я задал в вопросе?

Comment: Да, можно. Ставьте <form method="get" ...> На странице act.html напишите скрипт, который посмотрит, что передано через get и выведет это на экран

Comment: Можете подсказать, как писать этот скрипт на странице 'act.html'? Будет хорошо, если там не нужно будет писать 10 кг текста) xD

Comment: Можно. Поставьте в форме method=get. на следующей странице (act.html) в обработчик onLoad тега body добавьте функцию, которая разберет URI, выделит параметры и значения и заполнит форму.

Comment: @Magos, я не уверен что там есть jQuery. Вы не могли бы написать полноценный код js? У меня сейчас нет под рукой пк, а на телефоне писать код - то еще извращение;)

Comment: да там jquery особенно и не нужен. хватит и самого простого javascript. код - ниже